# How to save data as BlobProperty instead of multiple ListProperties?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, python-2.5

Currently I have the following code:

```
class User(db.Model):
    field_names = db.StringListProperty(indexed=False)
    field_values = db.StringListProperty(indexed=False)
    field_scores = db.ListProperty(int, indexed=False)

def fields_add(user_key_name, field_name, field_value, field_score):
    user = User.get(user_key_name)
    if user:
        try:
            field_index = user.field_names.index(field_name) # (1)
            user.field_values[field_index] = field_value
            user.field_scores[field_index] = field_score
        except ValueError:
            # field wasn't added to the list before
            user.field_names.append(field_name)
            user.field_values.append(field_value)
            user.field_scores.append(field_score)
        user.put()
```

It works well, but I would like to optimize that - serialize `field_name`, `field_value` and `field_score` and store in one `BlobProperty`:

```
class User(db.Model):
    fields = db.ListProperty(indexed=False)

    f = {
      'f': field_name,
      'v': field_value,
      's': field_score,
    }
    user.fields = simplejson.dumps(f)
```

But how should code (1) look like with such approach? How to find record for update?

Answer (score 1):

If `user.fields` is a list of dicts where `'f'` is the field name, this is one possible answer to your immediate question:

```
field_index = [field['f'] for field in user.fields].index(field_name)
```

It's not immediately clear why your revision is more optimal in your case, but I'll take your word for it.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize objects with json or pickle.
So for instance. If your model holds a property :     udata = db.BlobProperty()
The serialize an object like : ..udata = pickle.dumps(object).